# How to set the value of every second row and second column to blank in ssrs

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am currently showing a report in SSRS. I want to set the value of every second row - first and second column to blank/space. I cannot do it in the stored procedure since I use it for sorting by name and id.

e.g I have the below

```
Id  Name  Value
1    Car    1000
1    Car     10%
2    Van     500
2    Van      5%
```

What I want is:

```
Id   Name  Value
1     Car    1000
               10%
2     Van     500
               5%
```

Comment: SSRS is more commonly used with sql server - please confirm that your db server is mysql and that the question is correctly tagged.

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes the database server is mysql

Comment: Why not just group your table by ID and Name, the grouped columns will only appear once per distinct value?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear on the requirements, but it seems like you're seeing a duplication of data that you'd like to prevent.  This can probably be solved with an expression that checks the previous value for the same value. The following expression will compare the current cell value against the previous cell value and only show the value if the previous cell does not contain the same value.

```
=IIF(Previous(Fields!Name.Value) = Fields!Name.Value), "", Fields!Name.Value)
```

However, if I take this literally and you want an empty row after each entry and data doesn't matter -- you could simply insert a blank row into your details group.  The below image shows how to add a blank row.  Right click the outer edge of the tablix and insert a row inside the detail grouping.

[image: image1]

You can just leave the row blank and you should get results like the following image.

[image: image2]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I came up with another expression as well: =IIf((RowNumber(NOTHING) Mod 2) = 0, " ",Fields!BuyerName.Value)